# SQL from entity core taking 40x longer than raw SQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is the SQL generated by entity framework (Query insight https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLoZY.png)

```
SELECT
  t."Id" AS "Id1",
  t."PositionId" AS "PositionId1",
  t."OddsDecimal" AS "OddsDecimal1",
  t0."Id" AS "Id2",
  t0."PositionId" AS "PositionId2",
  t0."OddsDecimal" AS "OddsDecimal2"
FROM (
  SELECT
    f."Id",
    f."EventKey",
    f."BetCategory",
    f."CustomLine",
    f."CustomParticipant",
    f."PositionId",
    f."OddsDecimal",
    f."BetPosition"
  FROM
    "FanduelPositions" AS f
  WHERE
    f."LastUpdated" > (now() + INTERVAL $1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    d."Id",
    d."EventKey",
    d."BetCategory",
    d."CustomLine",
    d."CustomParticipant",
    d."PositionId",
    d."OddsDecimal",
    d."BetPosition"
  FROM
    "DraftkingsPositions" AS d
  WHERE
    d."LastUpdated" > (now() + INTERVAL $2) ) AS t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    f0."Id",
    f0."EventKey",
    f0."BetCategory",
    f0."CustomLine",
    f0."CustomParticipant",
    f0."PositionId",
    f0."OddsDecimal",
    f0."BetPosition"
  FROM
    "FanduelPositions" AS f0
  WHERE
    f0."LastUpdated" > (now() + INTERVAL $3)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    d0."Id",
    d0."EventKey",
    d0."BetCategory",
    d0."CustomLine",
    d0."CustomParticipant",
    d0."PositionId",
    d0."OddsDecimal",
    d0."BetPosition"
  FROM
    "DraftkingsPositions" AS d0
  WHERE
    d0."LastUpdated" > (now() + INTERVAL $4) ) AS t0
ON
  (((t."EventKey" = t0."EventKey")
      AND (t."CustomParticipant" = t0."CustomParticipant"))
    AND (t."BetCategory" = t0."BetCategory"))
  AND (t."CustomLine" = t0."CustomLine")
WHERE
  (t."BetPosition" <> t0."BetPosition")
  AND ((($5 / t."OddsDecimal") + ($6 / t0."OddsDecimal")) < $7)
```

This is the raw SQL I'm executing (query insight https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvX4e.png)

```
WITH
  tt AS (
  SELECT
    "Id",
    "EventKey",
    "BetCategory",
    "BetPosition",
    "OddsDecimal",
    "PositionId",
    "CustomLine",
    "CustomParticipant"
  FROM
    public."FanduelPositions" fd
  WHERE
    "LastUpdated" > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL $1 second
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "Id",
    "EventKey",
    "BetCategory",
    "BetPosition",
    "OddsDecimal",
    "PositionId",
    "CustomLine",
    "CustomParticipant"
  FROM
    public."DraftkingsPositions" dk
  WHERE
    "LastUpdated" > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL $2 second )
SELECT
  t1."PositionId",
  t1."OddsDecimal",
  t2."PositionId",
  t2."OddsDecimal"
FROM
  tt t1
JOIN
  tt t2
ON
  t1."EventKey" = t2."EventKey"
  AND t1."BetCategory" = t2."BetCategory"
  AND t1."CustomParticipant" = t2."CustomParticipant"
  AND t1."CustomLine" = t2."CustomLine"
  AND t1."BetPosition" <> t2."BetPosition"
  AND $3 / t1."OddsDecimal" + $4 / t2."OddsDecimal" < $5
```

The raw SQL takes ~200ms while the SQL generated by entity framework takes over 15seconds.

Here is my entity framework code -

```
var fd = dbContext.FanduelPositions.Where(x => x.LastUpdated > DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-15)).Select(x => new { x.Id, x.EventKey, x.BetCategory, x.CustomLine, x.CustomParticipant, x.PositionId, x.OddsDecimal, x.BetPosition });
var dk = dbContext.DraftkingsPositions.Where(x => x.LastUpdated > DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-15)).Select(x => new { x.Id, x.EventKey, x.BetCategory, x.CustomLine, x.CustomParticipant, x.PositionId, x.OddsDecimal, x.BetPosition });
var baseTable = fd.Concat(dk);

var positions = (from x in baseTable
                             join y in baseTable
                             on new { x.EventKey, x.CustomParticipant, x.BetCategory, x.CustomLine } equals new { y.EventKey, y.CustomParticipant, y.BetCategory, y.CustomLine } 
                             where
                                x.BetPosition != y.BetPosition && (1 / x.OddsDecimal + 1 / y.OddsDecimal) < .985
                             select new
                             {
                                 Id1 = x.Id,
                                 PositionId1 = x.PositionId,
                                 OddsDecimal1 = x.OddsDecimal,
                                 Id2 = y.Id,
                                 PositionId2 = y.PositionId,
                                 OddsDecimal2 = y.OddsDecimal
                             });
```

Is it possible to move the where clause to the on clause somehow? Is it possible to force entity framework to use a with statement? It is causing 2 full tablescans of each table.  I am not quiet sure how these 2 things are causing a 40x increase to the query time (even executing the entity framework SQL independently of .net) but I have added the query insights for these 2 queries as some possible information, I am not sure how to digest that information though.

Comment: Use the raw SQL query.  That's why they exist; to cover cases like these where the generated SQL is too complex or inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to the black-box of entity framework

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wanted to use RawSQL but I had to tie it to a specific model (`dbContext.FanduelPositions.FromSqlRaw(...)`) which causes entity framework to try and tie the return value to FanduelPositions causing an error to be thrown because the columns don't match up.  I am just trying to return a `toList()` of the results to an API endpoint.  Is something like this possible?

Comment: If your dataset isn't too large, just bring it into memory using a custom DTO.  Once it's in memory, you can slice and dice it any way you want.

Comment: Is putting your query in a View and get it from there via EF an option?

Answer (score 0):

See if following is faster

```
var groups = baseTable.GroupBy(x => new { y.EventKey, y.CustomParticipant, y.BetCategory, y.CustomLine });
var positions = groups.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => x.Where(z => (y.BetPosition != z=BetPosition) &&  (1 / y.OddsDecimal + 1 / z.OddsDecimal) < .985).Select(z => new
                             {
                                 Id1 = y.Id,
                                 PositionId1 = y.PositionId,
                                 OddsDecimal1 = y.OddsDecimal,
                                 Id2 = z.Id,
                                 PositionId2 = z.PositionId,
                                 OddsDecimal2 = z.OddsDecimal
                             }));
```